# Truncating column width in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading in large csv files into pandas some of them with String columns in the thousands of characters. Is there any quick way to limit the width of a column, i.e. only keep the first 100 characters?

Comment: Do you mean after the fact, or do you want/need to truncate them before they're even stored in the frame?

Comment: Before even stored would be great. Would an apply be the fastest way for after the fact?

Comment: Writing an apply right now. Is there a way to get the width of a column of type object?

Comment: `df['string col'].apply(lambda x: x[:100])` will keep only the first 100 characters

Comment: Would be nice to check if it needs to be truncated beforehand. Can't seem to find any attribute that gives the width.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you can read the whole thing into memory, you can use the `str` method for vector operations:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv("toolong.csv")
>>> df
   a                       b  c
0  1  1256378916212378918293  2

[1 rows x 3 columns]
>>> df["b"] = df["b"].str[:10]
>>> df
   a           b  c
0  1  1256378916  2

[1 rows x 3 columns]
```

Also note that you can get a Series with lengths using

```
>>> df["b"].str.len()
0    10
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

I was originally wondering if

```
>>> pd.read_csv("toolong.csv", converters={"b": lambda x: x[:5]})
   a      b  c
0  1  12563  2

[1 rows x 3 columns]
```

would be better but I don't actually know if the converters are called row-by-row or after the fact on the whole column.

Comment: ``converters`` are called row-by-row (by a cython function). I think the ``str`` conversion would be faster (your first example)

Comment: @Jeff: ah, good to know.  That means that if the strings were absurdly long and you didn't want to chunk it, you could use that to make sure you never had more than one row's worth of excess.

Comment: sounds right, this is just code inspectino (aka eye-balling). and you know how reliable that is :)